# change information in seperate divs with button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, html

I am trying to accomplish this effect but I'm sure the coding is incorrect. I want the image `DIV`s to swap content when each button is clicked. This is what I have so far, but I'm sure the code is incorrect. Is there a better way of achieving this? thanks, and forgive me for the noob question.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="item-1 content-item">
    I am the 1st image content
</div>

<div class="item-2 content-item" style="display: none;">
    I am the 2nd image content
</div>

<div class="item-3 content-item" style="display: none;">
    I am the 3rd image content
</div>

<div class="item-1 content-item">
    I am the content for item 1
</div>

<div class="item-2 content-item" style="display: none;">
    I am the content for item 2
</div>

<div class="item-3 content-item" style="display: none;">
    I am the content for item 3
</div>

<ul>
    <li class="change-item" data-item="1">Item 1</li>
    <li class="change-item" data-item="2">Item 2</li>
    <li class="change-item" data-item="3">Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('.change-item').click(function(){
    var this_item = $(this).attr("data-item");
    $('.content-item').hide();
    $('.item-' + this_item).fadeIn();  
});
```

Comment: Did you forget the code?

Comment: As with many things in JavaScript: you need to explain, clearly explan, what 'this' is, in context 'accomplish this effect'?

Comment: Yes, I forgot the code, sorry.  http://jsfiddle.net/3mJ3z/17/

Comment: What is the problem in the code.. Seems to be working fine !!

Comment: Which browser are you using OP? I tested it in Chromium and, as  Sushanth noted, it works fine.

Comment: Im using Firefox. I see its working fine, but just not sure if this is the correct way to do this. If it is, then I apologize for wasting time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple tips you might find helpful, even though it is working fine.

1. Since your items are actually grouped by number and the stuff in between is hidden, you could just group them together.
2. You should consider using id attributes in your markup. This makes it more clear that each one of your items is unique and makes the javascript run faster.
3. Your `<ul>` is technically in order, so it's more properly an `<ol>`. This is splitting hairs, and will give you numbers instead of bullet points, giving you more work to style it correctly. But it's worth mentioning.
4. Consider giving some indication that the list items are interactive. You could make them buttons or anchors (so they would display like hyperlinks). Or try a css rule for the cursor to make the mouse pointer change when they a user goes over the link.

Like this:

```
.change-item {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Put it all together, it might look something like this:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="item-1" class="content-item">
    <img src="/item-1.png"/>
    <p>I am the content for item 1</p>
</div>

<div id="item-2" class="content-item" style="display:none;">
    <img src="/item-2.png"/>
    <p>I am the content for item 2</p>
</div>

<div id="item-3" class="content-item" style="display:none;">
    <img src="/item-3.png"/>
    <p>I am the content for item 3</p>
</div>

<ol>
    <li><a href="#" class="change-item" data-item="1">Item 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="change-item" data-item="2">Item 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="change-item" data-item="3">Item 3</a></li>
</ol>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$('.change-item').click(function(){
    var this_item = $(this).attr("data-item");
    $('.content-item').hide();
    $('#item-' + this_item).fadeIn();
});
```

But as you can tell, your code is fully functional as is. You didn't do anything terribly wrong (good job!), these are just a few things that might make this page easier on you or your users.

Comment: Thank you Patrick. I am sure this will be very helpful and useful!